# How can I allow users to duplicate arrays each with a different user selected name?

Tags: ios, arrays

My app allows users to create and several several arrays, from the media picker, saving each with a different user selected name. How can I allow the user to make a duplicate of one of the arrays and save under a different file name?

example list shows user created arrays
array1
array2
array3

Now the user wants to create a new array just like array3 but they will delete a few items rather than create an entire new array.

So I want the user to be able to make a copy of array3 naming it array4 and then make a be able to a few changes to array4 and save time.

Hope that makes some sense.

After the media picker selection of songs, this is my save playlist method:

```
- (void)savePlaylist:(MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{
    NSArray* items = [mediaItemCollection items];
    if (items == nil)
    {
        return;
    }
    NSMutableArray* listToSave = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (MPMediaItem *song in items)
    {
         NSNumber *persistentId = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
        [listToSave addObject:persistentId];
    }
   //read playlist title
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
    defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *thissongsList;
    thissongsList  = [defaults objectForKey:@"savetextkey"];
    //save playlist
    defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: thissongsList forKey:@"savetextkey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: listToSave];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:_songsList];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a place for people to get answers on specific questions. With that said your question is to broad. You're asking for the community to give you a full solution instead of answering a technical issue you're having. You need todo some research and find out how to solution this on your own. Then if you run into technical issues while building your solution feel free to post them here with relevant example code to help the community answer your question.

Comment: I have tried everything I could find on how to duplicate an array but none of them worked. My feeling is it is probably a line or two of code that has eluded me. I don't have specific code as I have tried dozens of methods. I think this is the best place to ask. The technical issue I am having is being unable to duplicate an array and keep the original as well. I hope that is not asking too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking to duplicate an array is fine, but we don't even know what language you're using. If you are using Objective-C, then all you have todo in order to copy an array is send the "copy" command on an array. Example below.

```
NSArray *myArray = [oldArray copy];
```

This is called a "shallow copy" which means it'll only copy the pointer references and not the actual objects. If you need to make brand new instances of the objects, then you'll need to adopt the NSCopying protocol in your objects, and override the `copyWithZone` method.

If you are using Swift then you'll basically do the same thing. To copy the array you'll use the code below.

var myArray = oldArray

Then use the same NSCopying protocol if you want to make a deep copy.

That's it, that is all you've got todo to copy an array.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I am using objective-C. I do wish to make a new array with new instances of the objects. I have not used NSCopying protocol. Would I simply replace the word "copy", in your example, with "NSCopy" ?

Comment: @miken.mkndev, do you know if these statements would work: `NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: oldArray];` or `NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: oldArray];` ?

Comment: I don't know, I can try them. Remember I want a duplicate array that does not affect the original array when changes are made. I will try your suggestions to see if they create a duplicate array.

Comment: After the media picker selection of songs, this is my save playlist method, added to my original post above.

Comment: NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: oldArray]; Does seem to save the array. For some reason its not saving the new array into my list of saved arrays but I should be able to figure that out. Thanks!